# Azure devops pipeline triggers for abandoned PR

Tags: azure-devops, cicd

I'm working on an Azure devops pipeline and I already have two triggers in place. One for running on a Pull Request and one for running on Master

`- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest') }}:`

`- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:`

I need a trigger for when I abandon a PR to run a cleanup step.

Is there a trigger for abandoned PRs?

Comment: I checked your question as well as the answer. Please follow the steps and methods to try it first. If you have any questions and need help, we are happy to answer them.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Bouke sadly not